# How to hide get parameters from the URL by adding .htacess into a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can i hide get parameters from URL using `.htaccess`? I don't want to change `GET` to `POST` but I rather like to add `.htaccess` into a directory named xxx where the the page is located to hide parameters from the URL

I tried this but it doesn't change anything

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ts125/xxx/(.*) imdetail.php?sid=$1
RewriteRule ts125/xxx/(.*) imdetail.php?sid=$1=$1
RewriteRule ts125/xxx/(.*) imdetail.php?sid=$1
```

Comment: What url are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @starkeen I want to hide all parameters after `.php` i want to show like this `www.example.com/ts125/xxx/imdetail.php`

Comment: Is your htaccess located in /xxx folder?

Comment: yes its located in `/xxx` not in parent or publichtml. i also tried `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://example.com/ts125/xxx/imdetailt.php?sid=(.*) imdetailt.php`  but nothing happens to url no error nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in `/ts125/xxx/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ts125/xxx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ imdetail.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect

- site.com/ts125/xxx/foobar

to

- site.com/ts125/xxx/imdetail.php?sid=foobar.

Comment: no luck doesnt do anything and i uploaded the file but i  cant see the file listed may be i cant write `.htaccess` to the directory? May be thats the cause?